# Flask render_template does not reload site with new variables - am I thinking wrongly here?

Tags: python, flask

I am doing a private project and use Flask to create a Web App.

I want to display items, which are loaded from a SQL database, in a list.

In the default window a complete list of all items will be shown.

Using checkboxes as filter inputs on the site, I want to show updated items after a checkbox is being checked/unchecked. I do this using a EventListener. After checking/unchecking a box, the updated filter values are being forwarded by using the request.open command. In this command the filter values will be transformed to JSON-stringified values.

Thus a new HTML Request will be created and the for the filtering needed values will be inside the URL.
In my Python script, there is a special route, which handles the URLs which have those stringified values inside.

The values arrive correctly and also the SQL command gets the correct items from the database. But those values will not be shown correctly, when I hand them in to the render_template() method.

Do I have a flaw in my thinking there or should this work (if it should work, it should work though)?

Code for testing:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div>
                <button type="button" onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
            </div>
            <main>
                {% for name in names %}
                    {{ name.id }} {{ name.first_name }} {{ name.last_name }} <br>
                {% endfor %}
            </main>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script src="../static/javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.py:

```
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask,redirect, render_template
import json

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///db/test.db")

db_names = db.execute("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id;")


@app.route("/", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    """Show homepage with name list"""
    return render_template("index.html", names = db_names)

@app.route("/index/<first_name>, <last_name>", methods = ["GET"])
def indexfiltered(first_name, last_name):
    """Show homepage with filtered list"""
    first_names = (json.loads(first_name))
    last_names = (json.loads(last_name))
    filtered_names = db.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name = ? OR last_name = ?;", [first_names], [last_names])
    print(filtered_names)
    return render_template("index.html", names = filtered_names)
```

javascript.js:

```
function refresh() {
    var first_name = "Jehn"
    var last_name = "Wock"
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(first_name, last_name)
    request.open("GET", `/index/${JSON.stringify(first_name)}, ${JSON.stringify(last_name)}`)
    request.send();
}
```

Create database named test.db using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
        id int,
        first_name string,
        last_name string
);

INSERT INTO test(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (1, "John", "Wick");
INSERT INTO test(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (2, "Johnny", "Wicky");
INSERT INTO test(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (3, "Jehn", "Weck");
INSERT INTO test(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (4, "John", "Wock");
INSERT INTO test(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (5, "Jyhn", "Wyck");
INSERT INTO test(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (6, "Jihn", "Wick");
```

requirements.txt:

```
cs50
Flask
```

Tried as shown in the snippets above. I expected the page to reload/rerender with the new values, but it only shows the original values all over again. I do not want the page to reload fully, since it is only a small part of my app, which shows those items.

Comment: You can't render a template with an ajax request. In order to filter the results, make a request to your `indexfiltered` function, but return a json response instead of `render_template`. Then use that json response and manipulate the DOM in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer BcK! Will try it as soon as codespace is up again.

Did not know that `render_template` does not reload the template once it is loaded. Does this mean that only a full reload of the page with a new `@route` would solve the problem in the way I tried to solve it as seen above? Would be not elegant, but just curious if it would.

Comment: No, read my answer again. `render_template` normally works as it should, however there is a catch with the ajax requests (XMLHttpRequest) that you are making. It will not work that way. When the refresh button is pressed, redirect your browser to the `indexfiltered` route with `window.location.href` or something similar, instead of making an ajax get request.